# PostgresSql Environment variable $DATABASE_URL not set, and no connect string given

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

I am seeing a connection error when i try to read data from postgressql in my jupyter notebook. The error suggests:

```
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

As far as i can see the example format matches with my connection string provided.
I have also checked that i have updated version of sqlachemy.
What am i missing ?

[image]

```
engine=create_engine(f'postgresql://postgres:root@localhost/GoldPrices')
engine.connect()
```

```
#To load ipython-sql
%load_ext sql
```

```
%sql postgresql://postgres:root@localhost/GoldPrices
```

[image: postgresql]

Comment: Are you sure you are working with `ipython-sql` and not `jupysql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql:

> Legacy project

> IPython-SQL's functionality and maintenance have been eclipsed by JupySQL, a fork maintained and developed by the Ploomber team. Future work will be directed into JupySQL - please file issues there, as well!

So go here:

https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#

and then:

`pip install jupysql`

With `SQLAlchemy==2.0.23`.

Then:

```
%load_ext sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_url = "postgresql://postgres:@localhost/test"
engine = create_engine(db_url)
%sql engine
%sql select * from cell_per
```

Though if you want to stick with `ipython-sql`, per instructions here:

https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

Do the following:

```
%load_ext sql
%%sql postgresql://postgres:@localhost/test
select * from cell_per
```